Troubleshooting Ruby on Rails App Setup Errors on Mac M1
I recently switched to a 2021 MacBook M1 and am in the process of setting up my project on this new machine. I've successfully installed Ruby version 2.7.2 and NVM version 12.22.12. After successfully running bundle install, I encountered errors when attempting to execute rake db:create and rake stimulus_reflex:install. I'm unsure how to resolve these issues.
rake db:create --trace                                                                
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/factory_bot-6.4.5/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected (...
...method_missing(method_name, ...)
...                            ^~~
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/factory_bot-6.4.5/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...instance.send(method_name, ...)
...                              ^
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/factory_bot-6.4.5/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:42: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...nner.new.send(method_name, ...)
...                              ^
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/factory_bot-6.4.5/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:80: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/factory_bot-6.4.5/lib/factory_bot.rb:25:in `<main>'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/factory_bot_rails-6.4.3/lib/factory_bot_rails/railtie.rb:3:in `<main>'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/factory_bot_rails-6.4.3/lib/factory_bot_rails.rb:1:in `<main>'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
/Users/abdulwahab/Desktop/projects/golfpay360/config/application.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abdulwahab/Desktop/projects/golfpay360/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/abdulwahab/Desktop/projects/golfpay360/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:710:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/abdulwahab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'```


Can someone please help me resolve these errors?








you need ruby v3 to use method_missing(method_name, ...) syntax. or you have to downgrade factory_bot to v6.4.4
